# MBP 2011: Built-in screen mistakenly treated as external display

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, gpu

### System facts

- MBP (Early 2011) (15")
- OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.5)
- No external displays connected

### Chain of events

- *Discrete GPU (AMD Radeon HD 6490M) goes bust* **[REF-1]**
- *I managed to avoid the problem by disabling all GPU drivers to force system use of integrated drivers (intel)*

### Key problem

- Since the GPU failure, my system has seemingly begun to treat the built in 1440x900 screen as an external display - **this is what I want to fix**
- This is preventing me from using to GfxCardStatus.app to enforce integrated graphics mode (as the external display is apparently treated as a discrete GPU dependency)
- For various reason I'd like to stop the system from attempting to harness the discrete GPU

---

## Key question: *How can I make OSX treat the built-in display as such, thereby allowing me to enforce integrated-only graphics?*

---

***[REF-1]***
*Apparently a widespread issue, lots of MBP 2011s discrete GPUs are frying around this time of year as a result of manufacturing faults. [Google 'MBP 2011 GPU failure' for more information.](https://www.google.com/search?q=MBP+2011+GPU+failure&oq=MBP+2011+GPU+failure&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.381j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)*

***[FIG-1]***
[image: Combined screenshots]

Comment: Anyone at all... ?

Comment: Did you upgrade to yosemite since then and does the problem still persist?

Comment: I installed Yosemite GM on a separate partition at the time, booted it up, and could barely move the mouse due to the GPU requirements of the OS. Have not tried again since, would not know if post-release Yosemite fixes anything... but I doubt it.

Comment: i have the same macbook and osx yosemite runs just fine, you might want to try upgrading.
If you don't want to, try resetting the pram and nvram as described here:http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: I spent days praying that PRAM/NVRAM resets would work, finding they wouldn't, removing GPU drivers to force alternate drivers, etc. etc. I'll give Yosemite a try at some point, I suppose...

Comment: and a smc reset? http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Of course. Hence the last-plea Stack Exchange post.